# Remedy: create incident from WS without using first name and last name

Tags: email, service, web, remedy

I'm trying to create an incident in Remedy through the web service HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS. Everything is working fine however it would be better for me if I could use the submitter's mail address or login instead of his "first name" and "last name", which both are mandatory fields in the WSDL file. Is there a way to create the incident without using them?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom filter similar to HPD:HII:CreateIncident_020_GetPPLInfo (you can just save that as a copy).  Change the first namd/last name parameters with the email.

You can also post questions on the BMCDN forums, more remedy specific folks look at this forum.

https://communities.bmc.com/communities/community/bmcdn/bmc_it_service_support?view=overview

Answer (score 0):

I see your dilemma.  I believe you'd need to modify the out-of-box WSDL to make 'First Name' and 'Last Name' optional.  I think you can change the 'Nillable' property (see Figure 1) of each WSDL attribute to 'true' to accomplish your goal.  I haven't tested this method, but I think it will work.

You'll also need to add a filter that executes on submit of the form 'HPD:IncidentInterface_Create' to set both the 'First Name' and 'Last Name' fields using the email address as the lookup criteria.

It might be a good idea to create a copy of the out-of-box WSDL and modify the copy.  That way any hot-fixes provided by BMC will still operate correctly.  But, that's just my preference.

P.S. I tried to upload a screenshot of the 'Nillable' property, but evidently I don't have enough reputation points to do that (drat!)  :-)